# Trying to exec Python script using PHP

Tags: php, python, bash

I'm trying to exec python script using PHP, but python seems to dont work when exec by php.

I tryied this code to test

```
$cmdResult = shell_exec("ls & /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version & echo done");
```

Returned:

```
done
LICENSE
example.py
```

When I exec it on console (shell):

```
[root@local folder]# /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Anyone have any idea whats the problem?

Aditional info:

```
[root@local folder]# ls -all /usr/local/bin/py*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root apache      84 Jul 21 21:53 /usr/local/bin/pydoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 Jul 21 21:43 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root apache 4669791 Jul 21 21:53 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root apache    1674 Jul 21 21:53 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
```

Comment: Use [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of `shell_exec()`

Comment: didnt returned Python version aswell. passthru()

Comment: use `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: using && instead of & didnt also not returned python version. result: example.py LICENSE done (only changed the order from result)

Comment: did you replaced both `&`?

Comment: Yes. $cmdResult = passthru("ls && /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version && echo done"); echo $cmdResult;

Comment: What happens if you only execute `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version` ?

Comment: Empty result when executed by PHP and returns "Python 2.7.6" when executed on shell.

Comment: Does it have anything with permissions ? php is not root

Comment: I dont know.. I gave permission to apache.. still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shell command try using `&&` like so:

```
ls && /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version && echo done
```

so your code would read

```
$cmdResult = shell_exec("ls && /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version && echo done");
```